# How can I fix this loop to go over each url?

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

```
for url in urls:
    for page in range(0,26): #Remember to update the number of pages 
        #url = 'https://www.metacritic.com/game/switch/pokemon-sword/user-reviews?page='+str(page)
        headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        response  = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        #time.sleep(rand.randint(3,30)) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        review_dict ['product'] = soup.find('div', class_='product_title').find('h1').text
        for review in soup.find_all('div', class_='review_content'):
            if review.find('div', class_='name') == None:
                break
            review_dict['name'].append(review.find('div', class_='name').find('a').text)
            review_dict['date'].append(review.find('div', class_='date').text)
            review_dict['rating'].append(review.find('div', class_='review_grade').find_all('div')[0].text)
            if review.find('span', class_='blurb blurb_expanded'):
                review_dict['review'].append(review.find('span', class_='blurb blurb_expanded').text)
            else:
                review_dict['review'].append(review.find('div', class_='review_body').find('span').text)
```

I have that code, and I need to got through a couple of urls but I always get the same error (ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool)

This is the list  of urls :

```
urls = [
    'https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/world-of-warcraft-legion/user-reviews?page=', 
    'https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/world-of-warcraft-warlords-of-draenor/user-reviews?page=', 
    'https://www.metacritic.com/game/switch/pokemon-sword/user-reviews?page='
]
```

Comment: Sorry this is absolutely hideous.

Comment: Hi Javier Matamoros, welcome to Stack Overflow. There may be things you can do to simplify your code but I think your main problem is that you seem to trying to retrieve a lot of information from them servers in a short time which mat look like a network attack. So you probably need to space out through your retrieval and and to randomize it so that it still doesn't look like an attack. There's also the fact that some of the pages that you are trying to retrieve just don't exist which may trigger an anti-attack response.

Comment: But ethically, if you intend to retrieve a lot of information from that website, you should ask its owner about it.

Comment: The script **runs completely fine for me**. Can you retry now? And can you check if you can open those Metacritic URLs in a web browser?

Comment: Hey, I know it's really really bad, however, i've been learning to program for about 3 weeks, so I'm pretty new, saying something like "Is hideous" doesn't really help. On the other hand, this is merely for academic purposes, they do have an api but it is pricey. I would like to know how to simplify my code, that would be amazing. Thank you.